# Better way to do this code. Convert from string, Math.Round and handle negative numbers

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have an exercise where i have to convert string to whole number and be able to handle negative numbers. This kind of works but there has to be a better way to do this.

```
String nr = "-5.6";

double x = Convert.ToDouble(nr);       //Convert to double

double y = Math.Round(x);   //Round the nr
int r = Convert.ToInt32(x); //Convert to Int 
string t = r.ToString();    //Convert back to string so possible
textBox1.AppendText(t);     //to Append to textBox
```

Comment: What do you mean saying "better"?

Comment: You can move all your code to one line: `textBox1.AppendText(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(nr))).ToString());`. But I definitely don't think that's better. What does "better" mean to you?

Comment: Id leave a note for your exercise *giver* and say *"you shouldn't be storing numeric values as a string"* (extra marks.. or not)

Comment: Better as in shorter code. not as many lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go hero mode, and just do it in one line, depending on what you want the results to be

```
var nr = "-5.6";

var result = Math.Truncate(double.Parse(nr)).ToString() ; // -5
// or
var result = Math.Round(double.Parse(nr)).ToString() ; // -6
```

Though putting everything on one line as a hack, also if this is user input, you would probably want to use `double.TryParse` and validate against dirty little fingers

Answer (score 2):

Your way is fine; it is explicit and allows you complete control over each step of the conversion. It would be easy to modify it to change the rounding rules, for example, or to handle different number formats.

However if you want something very simple and short, you can do it in one line by using string.Format.

```
var result = string.Format("{0:N0}", float.Parse("-5.6"));
```

Comment: Nice answer, however Oh my eyes!, `$"{float.Parse("-5.6"):N0}"` interpolation for the win

Comment: Yes, oh my eyes! is right. In my experience, this sort of thing is rare; when it does come up, it requires absolute adherence to a specification. So I would probably end up writing it out explicitly as the OP has.